# Why am I getting nil for a belongs_to relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, belongs-to

I'm having a problem in my Ruby on Rails app with a model where a belongs_to relationship keeps ending up being nil.

Given the following models:

```
 class Chassis < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :model
   belongs_to :chassis_size
 end

 class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :chassis
 end

 class ChassisSize < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :chassis
 end
```

Now, I would expect in my chassis index view I would see both the model and the chassis_size data given:

```
 <% @chassis.each do |chassis| %>
    <%= chassis.id %><br />
    <%= chassis.model.name %><br />
    <%= chassis.chassis_size.size %><br />
 <% end %>
```

But I get an error that the chassis_size.size is nil:

```
 You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
 You might have expected an instance of Array.
 The error occurred while evaluating nil.size
```

Looking at the data in the database, everything appears to be correct.

I am not sure why model works but chassis_size does not. What am I missing? Why doesn't the chassis_size data appear to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is size a column in your chassis_sizes table?

If so, this is a reserved word in ruby, as it is the method for returning the length of an array.

Does every chassis have a chassis_size? Try this:

```
<% @chassis.each do |chassis| %>
    <%= chassis.id %><br />
    <%= chassis.model.name %><br />
    <% if chassis.chassis_size %>
        <%= chassis.chassis_size.description %>
    <% else %>
        No chassis_size exists for this chassis
    <% end %><br />
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, size is a column. I accept that I should rename it to something else...

BUT...
 
I have a description column on that table too, and using that results in an "undefined method `description' for nil:NilClass" error

Comment: Sure enough, I missed a key in the migration and didn't see the NULL values when I scrolled through the data. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem...but I'm pretty sure the data is correct....what do you mean you "missed a key"? Do you mean that some of the chassis are Null? Or some of their size is null?  For me, if I ask the class of the object it belongs to, it works, but if I ask for an attribute of that object, it says it's a nill class.